# Change data of one form from another form

Tags: c#, winforms, forms

My program is a testing. It contains some questions and some answers for them. I want to make it possible to add some questions. I created a `MenuStrip`, where it opens another `Form`, where I write new question and answers for them. I have su class to save questions in the main form:

```
public class Question
{
    public Question(string q_text,  Dictionary<string, bool> ans)
    {
        text = q_text;
        answers = ans;
        isAnswered = false;
    }
    public string text { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<string, bool> answers { get; set; }// = new Dictionary<RadioButton, bool>();
    public bool isAnswered;
}

public Dictionary<int, Question> questions = new Dictionary<int, Question>();
```

I set them to public, but there are still some problems. It can't see existing questions in the Dictionary. This is a method that adds new question in other form:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Form1 tmp = new Form1();
    Dictionary<string,bool> ans = new Dictionary<string,bool>();
    ans.Add(answer1.Text,checkBox1.Checked);
    ans.Add(answer2.Text,checkBox2.Checked);
    ans.Add(answer3.Text,checkBox3.Checked);
    ans.Add(answer4.Text,checkBox4.Checked);
    tmp.AddQuestion(textBox1.Text, ans);
}
```

Method in main form:

```
public void AddQuestion(string text, Dictionary<string, bool> ans)
        {
            Question q = new Question(text, ans);
            questions.Add(questions.Count + 1, q);
            GroupBox gb = new GroupBox();
            gb.Name = "GroupBox" + (questions.Count + 1);
            gb.Size = new Size(500, 200);
            gb.Location = new Point(40, loc);
            gb.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Aquamarine;

            Label q_text = new Label(); // текст питання
            q_text.Text = text;
            q_text.Font = new Font("Aria", 10, FontStyle.Bold);
            q_text.Location = new Point(10, 10);
            gb.Controls.Add(q_text);
            int iter = q_text.Location.Y + 30;
            if (CheckIfMuliple(questions.Count))
            {
                foreach (string key in ans.Keys)
                {
                    CheckBox rb = new CheckBox();
                    rb.Text = key;
                    rb.Size = new Size(120, 25);
                    rb.Location = new Point(q_text.Location.X + 10, iter);
                    iter += 30;
                    gb.Controls.Add(rb);
                }

            }
            else
                {
                    foreach (string key in ans.Keys)
                    {
                        RadioButton rb = new RadioButton();
                        rb.Text = key;
                        rb.Size = new Size(120, 25);
                        rb.Location = new Point(q_text.Location.X + 10, iter);
                        iter += 30;
                        gb.Controls.Add(rb);
                    }
                }
            this.Controls.Add(gb);   
        }
```

What's a better way to implement adding new question to main form?

Comment: What is the name of your `Main` form and also your `Child` form? Is `button1` in your `Child` form?

Comment: MainForm - Form1. And Child form is AddQuestion. Button1 in child form

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First change your Form1 constructor Access modifier to private.

Then add this part of code in Form1 class:

```
private static Form1 _Instance;
public static Form1 Instance
{
    get
    {
        if (_Instance == null)
            _Instance = new Form1();
        return _Instance;
    }
}
```

Now you access all form1 member easily:

```
Form1.Instance.AnyMember
```

This is a pattern called Singleton Pattern.

Comment: I did what you said. But now there is such error: Error 1 'KR.Form1.Form1()' is inaccessible due to its protection levelю

Comment: Maybe, because I need to modify data in Form1, not to get. This error happens, because it can't call method Application.Run(new Form1()); in Program.cs

Comment: I manage to avoid this error: just wrote Form1.Instance instead of new Form1()

Comment: It's all OK. But I face one problem: I can't create new Form that is inheritated from Form1. What should I do?